# IS there an automatic undefined behaviour checker in C++?

Tags: c++

A tool that checks every statement, declaration... and flag it if the standard says it is an undefined behaviour (e.g using an uninitialized int).

Comment: Check out the sanitizer from clang (and gcc)

Comment: Try UBSAN (part of Clang).

Comment: Look for *static analyzers* for C++. Note that no single analyzer will be able to find *all* instances of UB, but running multiple (together with high warning levels from the compiler of course) should help you find most.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I doubt it. There's quite a lot of run-time UB, especially now that we have threads. Using uninitialized ints across threads is a realistic risk, but hard to prove statically.